# awk/bash remove lines with an unique id and keep the lines that has the max/min value in a column under the same ID

Tags: bash, awk, count, max, min

If we have the following input and would like to firstly, detect if the cpd_number ($2) is unique in the file, remove the whole row.  In this case, the line with "cpd-6666666" should be removed.
Secondly, if there are multiple lines kept under the same "cpd_number",  only prints out the two lines which has the max and min "log_ratio" ($17).

```
targetID,cpd_number,Cell_assay_id,Cell_alt_assay_id,Cell_type_desc,Cell_Operator,Cell_result_value,Cell_unit_value,assay_id,alt_assay_id,type_desc,operator,result_value,unit_value,Ratio_operator,Ratio,log_ratio,Cell_experiment_date,experiment_date,Cell_discipline,discipline
49,cpd-7788990,1212,2323, IC50 ,,100,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,10,-1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-7788990,5555,6666, IC50 ,>,150,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,>,15,-1.176091259,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-7788990,8888,9999, IC50 ,,200,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,20,-1.301029996,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-6666666,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1.602059991,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
```

The ideal output should be

```
targetID,cpd_number,Cell_assay_id,Cell_alt_assay_id,Cell_type_desc,Cell_Operator,Cell_result_value,Cell_unit_value,assay_id,alt_assay_id,type_desc,operator,result_value,unit_value,Ratio_operator,Ratio,log_ratio,Cell_experiment_date,experiment_date,Cell_discipline,discipline
49,cpd-7788990,1212,2323, IC50 ,,100,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,10,-1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-7788990,8888,9999, IC50 ,,200,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,20,-1.301029996,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
```

I was trying to use awk count function but it doesn't seem to work quite well.  Could any guru kindly give some comments? Thanks!

Comment: You should also post the awk script you made. It can also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not as concise as the perl answer, here's a executable awk file:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS="," }

NR==1 {print; next}

{
  a[$2,$17]=$0

  h=high[$2]
  high[$2]=$17>h || h=="" ? $17 : h

  l=low[$2]
  low[$2]=$17<l || l=="" ? $17 : l
}

END {
  for(i in high) {
    if(low[i]!=high[i]) {
      print a[i,high[i]]
      print a[i,low[i]]
    }
  }
}
```

which:

- Prints the header row
- Stores whole lines in `a`, and `highs` and `lows` for each key
- In the `END`, walks the `high` array and prints lines where the `high` and `low` are different by retrieving them from `a`

Comment: Elegant solution too.  Could you explain this line a bit?  "high[$2]=$17>h || h=="" ? $17 : h" & "low[$2]=$17<l || l=="" ? $17 : l"

Comment: Sure.  `h` has been assigned to `high[$2]`.  The default lookup for an unassigned array is "", so h will either be "" or a previously assigned value.  The `high[]` lines uses a [ternary operator](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/02/awk-conditional-statements/) where the conditional is an OR (`||`) betwen either `$17>h`(greater than) or `h==""` being true.  If either is true, assign `$17` to `high[$2]`.  If not, reassign the `h` back to `high[$2]`.  The `low[]` code is similar but tests for `$17<l` (less than) in the conditional.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the obscure awk lines.  May I know where did you learn all these more advanced awk? Learning by doing or is there any recommended books?  All the awk tutorials I have read through are more like intermediate level though.

Comment: For reading, I suggest "The AWK Programming Language" although I bought mine so long ago it was cheap.  I've seen others here suggest "Effective awk Programming" though I have never seen a copy.  Mostly by doing though.  You can treat this site as a tutorial by picking questions out and trying to solve them yourself in "the home game version" (without reading other answers first or posting answers until you feel comfortable to do so).  Look for questions with well defined inputs/outputs.  Good luck!

Comment: @Chubaka Unfortunately with the growing popularity of advanced scripting languages like perl and python, awk has seen a steady decline. There aren't any new books so your best bet is to study the GNU awk user manual which is available for free. People generally resort to awk due to portability. Studying awk question and answers on this site will help too

Comment: awk's portability is a major concern.  It is limited to linux.  However, I still find it is very handy and powerful.

Comment: @Chubaka That is not entirely correct. You will find awk on pretty much all linux and unix distribution. What you'll probably not find is GNU awk on all unices.

Comment: Hi n0741337, could you also kindly check the post here?  I tried to modify your script here but encounter some difficulties.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24747469/awk-separate-rows-if-2-are-the-same-and-max-and-min-value-1-and-2-are-th

Answer (score 1):

It will be easier if you can give a try with `perl`:

```
perl -MList::Util=max,min -F, -lane '
    print if $.==1;
    $line{$F[1]}{$F[16]}=$_; 
    $count{$F[1]}++ 
}{
    for $key (keys %count) {
        next if $count{$key}==1; 
        print $line{$key}{ max keys %{$line{$key}} };
        print $line{$key}{ min keys %{$line{$key}} }
     }
' file
```

#### Output:

```
targetID,cpd_number,Cell_assay_id,Cell_alt_assay_id,Cell_type_desc,Cell_Operator,Cell_result_value,Cell_unit_value,assay_id,alt_assay_id,type_desc,operator,result_value,unit_value,Ratio_operator,Ratio,log_ratio,Cell_experiment_date,experiment_date,Cell_discipline,discipline
49,cpd-7788990,1212,2323, IC50 ,,100,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,10,-1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-7788990,8888,9999, IC50 ,,200,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,20,-1.301029996,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
```

#### Explanation:

- Use a core module (comes with every `perl` binary) to find min and max values of $17.
- Using `-F` split the lines on `,`.
- `-a` option splits the line on delimiter in to an `@F` array.
- If it is our first line, we print it
- We create a hash of hash with second column as key and 17th column as second tier key. The value is entire line
- We create a counter hash to keep counts of second column
- In the `END` block we iterate through our keys from counter hash. If the count is one we skip it.
- If the counter is greater than one we print the min and max of 17th column.

Comment: This perl solution looks pretty elegant.  I need to study a bit to read this script in details since i have zero knowledge in perl.