# awk separate rows if "$2 are the same and max and min value <= 1" and "$2 are the same and max and min value < 1"

Tags: bash, csv, awk

If we have an input file: input.csv

```
cpdID,cpd_number,Cell_assay_id,Cell_alt_assay_id,Cell_type_desc,Cell_Operator,Cell_result_value,Cell_unit_value,assay_id,alt_assay_id,type_desc,operator,result_value,unit_value,Ratio_operator,Ratio,log_ratio,Cell_experiment_date,experiment_date,Cell_discipline,discipline
49,cpd-7788990,1212,2323, IC50 ,,100,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,10,-1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-7788990,5555,6666, IC50 ,>,150,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,>,15,-2,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-7788990,8888,9999, IC50 ,,200,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,20,-3,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-6666666,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-1111,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-1111,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1.1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-1111,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1.2,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-1111,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1.3,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
```

We would like to separate this input.csv into 2 files so that we can do the following step: "do averages on rows if $2 are the same where the max minus min in $17 <= 1"

"If the $2 is the same and the max minus min in $17 <= 1 ", put it into 1 file

- Note: If there is an unique $2 itself, we would like to keep it here (cpd-6666666 as an example)
- Note: cpd-1111 ($17 max-min) = -1-(-1.3)=0.3 < 1

outputfile1.csv

```
cpdID,cpd_number,Cell_assay_id,Cell_alt_assay_id,Cell_type_desc,Cell_Operator,Cell_result_value,Cell_unit_value,assay_id,alt_assay_id,type_desc,operator,result_value,unit_value,Ratio_operator,Ratio,log_ratio,Cell_experiment_date,experiment_date,Cell_discipline,discipline
49,cpd-6666666,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-1111,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-1111,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1.1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-1111,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1.2,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-1111,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1.3,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
```

"If the $2 is the same and the max minus min in $17 > 1", put it into another file

outfile2.csv (where max & min in $17=-1-(-3)=2 > 1)

```
cpdID,cpd_number,Cell_assay_id,Cell_alt_assay_id,Cell_type_desc,Cell_Operator,Cell_result_value,Cell_unit_value,assay_id,alt_assay_id,type_desc,operator,result_value,unit_value,Ratio_operator,Ratio,log_ratio,Cell_experiment_date,experiment_date,Cell_discipline,discipline
49,cpd-7788990,1212,2323, IC50 ,,100,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,10,-1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-7788990,5555,6666, IC50 ,>,150,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,>,15,-2,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-7788990,8888,9999, IC50 ,,200,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,20,-3,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
```

Here is the attempt modifying from the following link

[awk/bash remove lines with an unique id and keep the lines that has the max/min value in a column under the same ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543486/awk-bash-remove-lines-with-an-unique-id-and-keep-the-lines-that-has-the-max-min)

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS="," }

NR==1 {print; next}

{
  a[$2,$17]=$0

  h=high[$2]
  high[$2]=$17>h || h=="" ? $17 : h

  m=mid[$2]
  mid[$2]=l<$17<h || m=="" ? $17 : m

  l=low[$2]
  low[$2]=$17<l || l=="" ? $17 : l
}

END {
  for(i in high) {
    if(high[i]-low[i]<=1) {
      print a[i,high[i]]
      print a[[i,mid[i]]
      print a[i,low[i]]
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
cpdID,cpd_number,Cell_assay_id,Cell_alt_assay_id,Cell_type_desc,Cell_Operator,Cell_result_value,Cell_unit_value,assay_id,alt_assay_id,type_desc,operator,result_value,unit_value,Ratio_operator,Ratio,log_ratio,Cell_experiment_date,experiment_date,Cell_discipline,discipline
49,cpd-1111,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-1111,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-1111,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1.3,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-6666666,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-6666666,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
49,cpd-6666666,8888,9999, IC50 ,,400,uM,1334,1331,Ki,,10,uM,,40,-1,12/6/2006 0:00,2/16/2007 0:00,Cell,Enzyme
```

For unknown reasons, this script cannot print out the middle range value(s) correctly.   May I know if any guru has comments/solutions?

Comment: I'm surprised that even runs. I didn't think `a < b < c` was a valid awk statement. Split that comparison into two pieces and see if it works.

Comment: a < b < c can still print out results.

Comment: You appear to be trying to use a `mid` array to catch all the rows which are not min/max and that won't work because `mid` will only ever contain a single row.  Furthermore, `a` will only catch unique combinations of every `$2,$17`.  If the file is grouped by `$2`(as it appears to be), you can use a more straight forward technique of testing when `$2` changes in the file to decide how to manipulate the data.

Comment: I see.  So even we give the mid array a range, there is no way to get multiple rows in awk?

Comment: "If the file is grouped by $2(as it appears to be), you can use a more straight forward technique of testing when $2 changes in the file to decide how to manipulate the data."  Could you kindly offer some examples of "straight forward technique of testing when $2 changes"?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this, which is an example of processing each group as it's id changes:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {FS=","; f1="a"; f2="b"}

FNR==1 { print $0 > f1; print $0 > f2; next }

$2!=last_id && FNR > 2 { handleBlock() }

{ a[++cnt]=$0; m[cnt]=$17; last_id=$2 }

END { handleBlock() }

function handleBlock() {
  if( m[1]-m[cnt]<=1 ) fname = f1
  else fname = f2
  for( i=1;i<=cnt;i++ ) { print a[i] > fname }
  cnt=0
}
```

It's an executable awk file.  When put it into a file called `awko` and `chmod +x awko` it can be run like `awko data` for an input file called "data".

The script I wrote for the other question was based on me assuming the the input order of the file elements were unknown - where the `$2` fields could be in any order and that only the min and max values mattered.  In this question, the OP would like to send all rows related to the `$2` field to one file or another based on the min/max values.

The input file for this question has the following properties which this script is dependent on:

- The header is on the first line
- The `$2` fields are grouped
- The max value is the first element of the group
- The min value is the last value of the group

Where there's a resource list that's sorted by the resource id, one common algorithm for minimally loading the data is to only load it when the resource id changes.  The same can be done for processing grouped entries here.  Take an example like:

```
a
a
a
b <- this is a good place to process all the prior "a" entries
b
c <- process "b" entries here
c
EOF <- the end of the file.  process the last group ( the "c" entries here )
```

With that in mind, here's a break down of the script:

- Set the `FS` and some output file names in `BEGIN` block ( "a" and "b" for my testing )
- The first line is the header - put it in each file, `f1` and `f2`.
- If `$2 != last_id`, call the `handleBlock()` function to process it.
- Store the whole line in array `a`, `$17` in array `m` and set `last_id=$2` ( the array names are horrible ).
- The `cnt` variable indicates how many entries are in each group ( what I called a block )
- `handleBlock()` will only get called when the `$2` id changes or at the end of the file to catch the last group in the `END` block.
- `handleBlock() tests the OP's condition using`m`( max is`m[1]`and min is m[cnt] ) to determine the output file name and then prints all elements from`a` to the chosen filename.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!  However, when "awk -f average2.awk input.csv", nothing seems to be generated.  Guess we might need to wait your detail explanation to fully understand this script and hence modify it.

Comment: Why do you call `handleBlock()` in-line as well as at `END`? Won't that just always print the last line?

Comment: @ssdecontrol - no group is printed until after it has been seen in its entirety.  The `handleBlock()` is for catching the last group whose end is only known by the end of the file being reached.  When the `END` block is commented out, only the `cpd-6666666` data row is written to `a`.

Comment: It is really an elegant approach.  Just to double check: handleBlock() is not an awk built in function right? The Google search suggests nothing.

Comment: @Chubaka - The function is defined locally at the end of the file in the `function handleBlock() { ... }` code.  Functions are a nice place to put code called more than once.  Here's a link to the GNU Awk docs for [user defined functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/User_002ddefined.html#User_002ddefined).

Comment: So handleBlock here is a user define function.  Got it.  If we would like to do average of f1 group (max-min diff <=1), just insert "m[cnt]/++cnt" in the script doesn't seem to work.  Do we need to build another "END { handleBlock() }" block for the average and print out the average in $17 and together with the whole line $0?

Comment: @Chubaka - You need to sum over the values in `m`.  For example `for( i=1;i<=cnt;i++ ) { sum+=m[i] }`.  You can get the avg from the sum then.  You'd need to remember to reset `sum=0` later.  Because of the header line, there was an extra call to `handleBlock()` which I've removed.

Comment: I make the line right after "else fname = f2" become "for( i=1;i<=cnt;i++ ) { sum+=m[i];b=sum/cnt}{ print a[i] > fname }" and the output doesn't seem to be right.

Comment: @Chubaka - This is a lot for the comments - how about opening a new question?

Comment: Yes, it is getting confusing.  I will open a new question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24769629/awk-separate-rows-based-on-2-and-17-and-do-average-on-17

Comment: The new question is above. Thanks.